# To retrieve site lists where user has access from DB

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, 2016, content-database

I am trying to retrieve all the sites a particular user has access from the content database. But not able to get all the sites. Somehow I can get site collections where user has access but still not able to get the sub sites. Any leads please.

Comment: can you share your code? you want to get the all site collections and subsite where a particular user has access?

Comment: Yes I am trying to get the same. I was trying it on sql itself, but not getting appropriate tables.

Answer (score 2):

Directly querying the database is not supported and it put your farm at risk. So please avoid it.

You can run powershell script to get the same results. [You can try the below script](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Report-Where-and-How-fe52b725)

Read the explanation over here:[How to Determine Where a User Has Been Granted Access in SharePoint 2010](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rcormier/2012/10/23/how-to-determine-where-a-user-has-been-granted-access-in-sharepoint-2010/)

```
$ver = $host | select version 
if($Ver.version.major -gt 1) {$Host.Runspace.ThreadOptions = "ReuseThread"} 
if(!(Get-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ea 0)) 
{ 
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell 
} 

## 
#Set Script Variables 
## 

$WebApplicationURL = "http://Contoso.com" 
$UnwantedDomainPrefix = "OldContoso" 
$LoggingDirectory = "C:\PermissionReport\" 

## 
#Load Functions 
## 

Function EnsureLoggingDirectory ($LoggingDirectory) 
{ 
    if(!(Test-Path $LoggingDirectory)) 
    { 
    $LoggingDirectory 
    Set-Variable -name Filename -Value ("$LoggingDirectory\SecurityReport_" +$StartTime +".txt") -Scope Script 
    Write-Host "Path " $LoggingDirectory " does not exist. `r`nCreating Directory" 
    New-Item -Path $LoggingDirectory -ItemType Directory 
    } 
} 

Function TrimDirectory ($LoggingDirectory) 
{ 
    if($LoggingDirectory.EndsWith("\")) 
    { 
        Set-Variable -Name LoggingDirectory -Value ($LoggingDirectory.Substring(0, ($LoggingDirectory.Length - 1))) -Scope Script 
    } 
} 

## 
#Start Script Execution 
## 
$StartTime = (Get-Date -UFormat "%Y-%m-%d_%I-%M-%S %p").tostring() 
TrimDirectory $LoggingDirectory 
EnsureLoggingDirectory $LoggingDirectory 
$Filename = "$LoggingDirectory\SecurityReport_" +$StartTime +".txt" 
"Security Report: $StartTime `r`n" | Out-File $Filename -Force 
"Finding Users Beginning with "  + $UnwantedDomainPrefix + "\ and NTAuthority" | Out-File $Filename -Append 

$AllSites = Get-SPSite -WebApplication $WebApplicationURL -Limit All 
foreach($Site in $AllSites) 
{ 
    $AllWebs = $Site.Allwebs 
    "`r`n`r`nSite: " +$Site.URL | Out-File $Filename -Append 
    foreach($Web in $AllWebs) 
    { 
        if($Web.HasUniqueRoleAssignments) 
        { 
            if($Web.isrootweb) 
            { 
                "`r`nweb '" + $Web.url + "' is Root Web and has unique permissions" | Out-File $Filename -Append 
            } 
            else 
            { 
                "`r`nWeb '" + $Web.url + "' is using unique permissions" | Out-File $Filename -Append 
            } 
            $AllLists = $Web.lists 
            $WebRoleAssignments = $Web.RoleAssignments 
                foreach($WebRoleAssignment in $WebRoleAssignments) 
                { 
                    if($WebRoleAssignment.member.userlogin) 
                    { 
                        if($WebRoleAssignment.Member.userlogin.split("\")[0] -eq $UnwantedDomainPrefix -or $WebRoleAssignment.Member.userlogin.split("\")[0] -eq "NT Authority") 
                        { 
                            "User '" + $WebRoleAssignment.Member + "' has been assigned '" + ($WebRoleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings | select name).name + "'" | Out-File $Filename -Append 
                        } 
                    } 
                    else 
                    { 
                        $allWebUsers = $WebRoleassignment.member.users 
                        foreach($WebUser in $AllWebUsers) 
                        { 
                            if($WebUser.userlogin.split("\")[0] -eq $UnwantedDomainPrefix -or $WebUser.userlogin.split("\")[0] -eq "NT Authority") 
                            { 
                                "User '" + $WebUser.Userlogin + "' has been added to the '" + $WebRoleAssignment.member.name + "' group" | Out-File $Filename -Append 
                            } 
                        } 
                    } 
                } 
            foreach($List in $AllLists) 
            { 
                if($List.HasUniqueRoleAssignments) 
                { 
                    "`r`nList '" + $List.title + "' is using unique permissions `r`nURL: " + $WebApplicationURL +$List.DefaultViewURL | Out-File $Filename -Append 
                    $RoleAssignments = $List.RoleAssignments 
                    foreach($RoleAssignment in $RoleAssignments) 
                    { 
                        if($RoleAssignment.member.userlogin) 
                        { 
                            if($RoleAssignment.Member.userlogin.split("\")[0] -eq $UnwantedDomainPrefix -or $RoleAssignment.Member.userlogin.split("\")[0] -eq "NT Authority") 
                            { 
                                "User '" + $RoleAssignment.Member + "' has been assigned '" + ($RoleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings | select name).name + "'" | Out-File $Filename -Append 
                            } 
                        } 
                        else 
                        { 
                            $allUsers = $Roleassignment.member.users 
                            foreach($User in $AllUsers) 
                            { 
                                if($user.userlogin.split("\")[0] -eq $UnwantedDomainPrefix -or $user.userlogin.split("\")[0] -eq "NT Authority") 
                                { 
                                    "User '" + $User.Userlogin + "' has been added to the '" + $RoleAssignment.member.name + "' group" | Out-File $Filename -Append 
                                } 
                            } 
                        } 
                    } 
                } 
            } 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But this was the first approach that went for. Since it is a bit time consuming so i was trying to do something by directly querying the DB.

Comment: But DB approach is risky and not supported. read this article https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/841057/support-for-changes-to-the-databases-that-are-used-by-office-server-pr  read this "Read operations addendum"